# Error when installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails on MAC OS X Lion. (My Xcode is version 4.3)
(I've installed Rails 3.2.2)

No matter if I use:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

or:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

My terminal shows:

```
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Has anyone encountered the same situation?

---

```
AlexHo@Nien-Yi-Hos-MacBook:~$ rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

---

```
AlexHo@Nien-Yi-Hos-MacBook:~$ cat /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
[2012-03-03 04:15:53] make 
        CC = clang
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1 -Wl,-unexported_symbol,_Init_* -Wl,-unexported_symbol,*_threadptr_*  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   
    SOLIBS = 
linking miniruby
rbconfig.rb unchanged
generating enc.mk
generating prelude.c
compiling prelude.c
linking static-library libruby.1.9.1-static.a
linking shared-library libruby.1.9.1.dylib
generating encdb.h
encdb.h unchanged
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
installing default bug libraries
installing default resize libraries
installing default bug libraries
installing default bug libraries
installing default funcall libraries
installing default dot.dot libraries
installing default old_thread_select libraries
installing default numhash libraries
installing default string libraries
installing default wait_for_single_fd libraries
installing default bigdecimal libraries
installing default continuation libraries
installing default coverage libraries
installing default curses libraries
installing default date_core libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing digest libraries
installing default digest libraries
installing default bubblebabble libraries
installing default md5 libraries
installing default rmd160 libraries
installing default sha1 libraries
installing default sha2 libraries
installing dl libraries
installing default dl libraries
installing default callback libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default etc libraries
installing default fcntl libraries
installing default fiber libraries
installing default fiddle libraries
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing default iconv libraries
installing default console libraries
installing default nonblock libraries
installing default wait libraries
installing default libraries
installing default generator libraries
installing default parser libraries
installing default complex libraries
installing default rational libraries
installing default nkf libraries
installing default objspace libraries
installing default openssl libraries
installing default pathname libraries
installing default psych libraries
installing default pty libraries
installing default cparse libraries
compiling readline.c
readline.c:1499:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^
readline.c:69:42: note: instantiated from:
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/readline/readline.h:449:14: note: 'rl_username_completion_function' declared here
extern char *rl_username_completion_function PARAMS((const char *, int));
             ^
    1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
    make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: Well, what's in the log file referenced?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've updated in the question.

Comment: Please paste the output of `cat /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log` into the question.

Comment: @TheDelChop I've updated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! In my case I tried `m8:~ m8$ cd $HOME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318/ext/readline
m8:readline m8$ ruby extconf.rb -- --with-readline-dir="$HOME/.rvm/usr" and if I run `m8:readline m8$ make install` afterwards I get a lot of weird `cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o readline.bundle readline.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L/Users/m8/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 ` … stuff

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem myself, and after a great deal of struggle and searching (not one site had the complete solution), here's what I finally came up with:

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf readline-6.2.tar.gz
cd readline-6.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
cd shlib
sed -e 's/-dynamic/-dynamiclib/' Makefile > Makefile.good
mv Makefile.good Makefile
cd ..
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rvm install 1.9.3 -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me for **1.9.3**-- still having trouble with **1.8.7**

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at this, it seems that your problem is with readline, and rvm has a whole section about working with readline errors.

http://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Comment: I've installed rails 3.2.2 now, but still cannot update ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3....