# Ruby not compiling on mountain lion

Tags: ruby, xcode, terminal, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

hi i am trying to get ruby to compile on osx 10.8 mountain lion with rvm, though i keep getting the following error

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
Removing /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194...
it seems that /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 is already non existent.
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p194 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p194 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p194 environments...
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p194 binaries...
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p194 to /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, the best way to avoid any problems with that is
[osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see make.log file and the errors? It might be popular readline error. For that refer this.

[Error when installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539031/error-when-installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Or,

[Make error installing Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm OSX Lion 10.7.2 XCode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813231/make-error-installing-ruby-1-9-2-via-rvm-osx-lion-10-7-2-xcode-4-2)

[Make error installing Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM and Readline under OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970545/make-error-installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-and-readline-under-osx-lion)